# Operator overloading?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

```
 MyClass & operator=(const MyClass &rhs);
```

What is the meaning of "&"? Why not is `My Class` instead of `MyClass &` ?

Comment: Probably very helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-pointer-variable-and-reference-variable-in-c. By the way, googling "ampersand in C++ parameter" yields me tons of relevant results.

Comment: I think you need to learn the basic fundamentals of C++. Try a [good book](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/10077).

Answer (score 2):

The `&` simply means that the return value of `operator =` is a *reference.*

This has nothing to do with operator overloading.  It's the same syntax with a normal function definition:

```
MyClass& foo()
{
  return *this; // returns a reference to MyClass instance
}

MyClass foo()
{
  return *this; // returns a copy of MyClass instance
}
```

Comment: And what meaning of `MyClass* foo()` ?

Comment: @DungProton, that means it returns a *pointer*.  But this is really basic, fundamental stuff.  Blindly asking this on stackoverflow probably isn't going to help you much.  You should read a good introductory C++ book.

Answer (score 0):

returning `MyClass&` is just to make operator '=' work in chain.
Returning `MyClass&` or something different doesn't add any effect in overloading '='.

Returing `MyClass&` helps us use '=' similar the way we use it on built-in data types.
eg.

```
int x = y = z = 123;
```

For similar discussion, refer Thinking in C++, (Discussion on iostreams).